# trigger to set date automatic after update

Tags: triggers, oracle-apex

Some background info: i have a table named defects which has column named status_id and another column named date_closed ,i want to set date_closed after status_id has been updated
i already try to do this using after update trigger with the following code:

```
after update on eba_bt_sw_defects
for each row
declare
    l_status number(20) := null;
begin
 select status_id into l_status  from eba_bt_sw_defects D,eba_bt_status S where D.status_id = S.id;
  if  l_status in ( select id from eba_bt_status where is_open = 'N' and NVL(is_enhancement,'N')='N') then
      :NEW.DATE_CLOSED  := LOCALTIMESTAMP ; 
 end if;
end;
```

but an error occured ( subquery not allowed in this contextCompilation failed)
i want a help

Comment: We don't have your tables, and you didn't use table aliases for all columns involved so it is impossible to guess which column belongs to which table, and that's what we need to know.

Comment: The short answer is not to query `eba_bt_sw_defects`, just use the appropriate `:new` or `:old` attribute.  I don't understand what you'd want your initial `select` to do if there was more than 1 row in the table.  Or what you'd want your cursor loop to do-- that query will return the same number of rows regardless of what you're inserting into your table so it will either always set `date_closed` or never set `date_closed` based on the data in the `eba_bt_status` table.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things that need fixing in your code:

- In a trigger *do not* select from the table the trigger you're on. This will probably raise a `ORA-04091: table name is mutating, trigger/function may not see it` error.
- `IF l_variable IN (SELECT ...)`  is not a valid oracle syntax. It raises `PLS-00405: subquery not allowed in this context`

I don't have your data so here is a similar example:

```
drop table todos;
drop table statuses;
-- create tables
create table statuses (
    id                             number generated by default on null as identity 
                                   constraint statuses_id_pk primary key,
    status                         varchar2(60 char),
    is_open                        varchar2(1 char) constraint statuses_is_open_ck
                                   check (is_open in ('Y','N'))
)
;

create table todos (
    id                             number generated by default on null as identity 
                                   constraint todos_id_pk primary key,
    name                           varchar2(255 char) not null,
    close_date                     timestamp with local time zone,
    status_id                      number
                                   constraint todos_status_id_fk
                                   references statuses on delete cascade
)
;



-- load data
 
insert into statuses (id, status, is_open ) values (1, 'OPEN', 'Y' );
insert into statuses (id, status, is_open ) values (2, 'COMPLETE', 'N' );
insert into statuses (id, status, is_open ) values (3, 'ON HOLD', 'Y' );
insert into statuses (id, status, is_open ) values (4, 'CANCELLED', 'N' );
commit;

insert into todos (name, close_date, status_id ) values ( 'Y2 Security Review', NULL, 1 );

-- triggers
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER todos_biu BEFORE
  INSERT OR UPDATE ON todos
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  l_dummy NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT
    1
    INTO l_dummy
    FROM
    statuses
   WHERE
      is_open = 'N' AND
    id = :new.status_id;

  :new.close_date := localtimestamp;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN no_data_found THEN
    -- I'm assuming you want close_date to NULL if todo is re-opened.
    :new.close_date := NULL; 
END todos_biu;
/

update todos set status_id = 2;

select  * from todos;
id  name                close_date                      status_id
1   Y2 Security Review  11-MAY-22 05.27.04.987117000 PM 2
```